# name = 0 when trying to print Column names of pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Filtering on Date columns

```
dateCols = c[newDF.columns.str.contains('Date', case = False)]
dateCols
```

Output:

```
Index(['A. Date ', 'B.Date', 'C.D date'], dtype='object', name=0)
```

##Infact I see name = 0 even when I print newDF.columns

When I try to change the above columns to Date using:

```
newDF[dateCols] = pd.to_datetime(newDF[dateCols].stack(), errors='coerce').unstack()
```

I am getting error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [124], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 dateCols = newDF.columns[newDF.columns.str.contains('Date', case = False)]
      3 dateCols
----> 4 newDF[dateCols] = newDF[[dateCols]].apply(pd.to_datetime)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3512, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3510     if is_iterator(key):
   3511         key = list(key)
-> 3512     indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
   3514 # take() does not accept boolean indexers
   3515 if getattr(indexer, "dtype", None) == bool:

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:5782, in Index._get_indexer_strict(self, key, axis_name)
   5779 else:
   5780     keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = self._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
-> 5782 self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
   5784 keyarr = self.take(indexer)
   5785 if isinstance(key, Index):
   5786     # GH 42790 - Preserve name from an Index

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:5842, in Index._raise_if_missing(self, key, indexer, axis_name)
   5840     if use_interval_msg:
   5841         key = list(key)
-> 5842     raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   5844 not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
   5845 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")

KeyError: "None of Index(['A. Date ', 'B.Date', 'C.D date'], dtype='object', name=0) are in the [columns]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate your error, but I did not receive any errors.

Code used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A.Date': ['2020-01-01'] * 10, 'B.Date': ['2020-01-01'] * 10, 'C.Date': ['2020-01-01'] * 10, 'other': np.arange(10)})
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Date', case=False)]
```

Which shows for cols:

```
Index(['A.Date', 'B.Date', 'C.Date'], dtype='object')
```

Finally using your last statement:

```
df[cols] = pd.to_datetime(df[cols].stack(), errors='coerce').unstack()
```

Edit: when looking into the logs we see the code:

```
newDF[dateCols] = newDF[[dateCols]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

This should be changed to the following code to resolve your problems.

```
newDF[dateCols] = newDF[dateCols].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: I am on 3.8 and I still have the error. TBH how I reached to the dataframe is by concatenating multiple .txt files and trimming white spaces.                  
`dfList = []
for f in fList:
    noSpaceLst = [] 
    with open(f) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            subbed = re.sub('\s{2,}', '', line.strip())
            noSpaceStr.append(subbed)
    #print(noSpaceStr[4])
    actData =  [noSpaceStr[4]]+ noSpaceStr[6:]
    df = pd.DataFrame([sub.split("|") for sub in actData])
    new_header = df.iloc[0] 
    df = df[1:] 
    df.columns = new_header 
    dfList.append(df)`

Comment: Have you checked my last suggestion? If so, could you confirm whether the problem has been resolved?

Comment: I did and that was resolved. But I still see the name = 0 when I print the columns. Thank You